# How can I do something like this? on rails active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to achieve something like this in rails active record.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tires 
JOIN comparison_prices 
WHERE comparison_prices.simple_tire_price < tires.web_price 
  AND comparison_prices.simple_tire_price >= tires.web_price - 5
```

Currently I have something like this:

```
@tires = Tire.all
@tires = @tires.joins(:comparison_price).where('tires.web_price > 0')
@tires = @tires.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10).order(:id)
```

Comment: Please try to edit a better title it tells quite little about your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your `Tire` model `has_one :comparison_price` you can just write:

```
@tires = Tire.joins(:comparison_price)
             .where('comparison_prices.simple_tire_price < tires.web_price')
             .where('comparison_prices.simple_tire_price >= tires.web_price - 5')
             .paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10).order(:id)
```

Or:

```
@tires = Tire.joins(:comparison_price)
             .where('comparison_prices.simple_tire_price BETWEEN tires.web_price - 5 AND tires.web_price')
             .paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10).order(:id)
```

Comment: you also need to provide pagination

Comment: @Jedidiah: I updated my answer to joins `comparison_price` (singular) because you have a `has_one` relationship. Please note that the SQL query still needs the plural tables name.

Comment: Thanks @spickermann one last querstion is this one achievable too?

SELECT
  *
FROM
  tires
JOIN
  comparison_prices
USING
  (id)
WHERE
(
  (comparison_prices.simple_tire_price < tires.web_price AND comparison_prices.simple_tire_price >= tires.web_price - 5)
OR
  (comparison_prices.walmart_price < tires.web_price AND comparison_prices.walmart_price >= tires.web_price - 5)
)

Comment: @Jedidiah Sure, just pass strings to `joins` and `where`: `Tire.joins("comparison_prices USING (id)").where("WHERE ( (comparison_prices.simple_tire_price < tires.web_price AND comparison_prices.simple_tire_price >= tires.web_price - 5) OR (comparison_prices.walmart_price < tires.web_price AND comparison_prices.walmart_price >= tires.web_price - 5)")`